# Reference Request-Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I am Studying Master's in Mathematics.
In my bachelors, I had learnt linear algebra from Sheldon Axler. I can solve problems from that without facing any issues.

Now In my Masters, My teacher is teaching Linear ALgebra from Matrix point of view.

It includes topics Row-space of a matrix, column sapce of a matrix and related theories. It usually deals with the theories of Rank, Rowspace, Column Space and so on.
I mean that This is totally new for me and I am unable to crack most of the problems.
Hence I would request you all to kindly suggest me best books for linear algebra, which will help me through these theories. I wish it must include Good Theory and a great number of problems, starting from basics to advanced level.

Comment: Hoffman and kunze linear algebra  is one of my favourite

Comment: Problems and Theorems in Linear Algebra , by V. V. Prasolov is the best choice I think

Answer (score 2):

I highly advise you to read Gilbert Strang's *Linear Algebra and its applications*. Although it is a rather old text book, he manages to convey basic concepts such as vector spaces in an easy way and aims at giving you a good intuition between the concepts involved in linear algebra. There are also many illustrations which help understanding the concepts even better.

Moreover, the book mentions several applications of linear algebra, ranging from physics to game theory.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Serge Lang - Linear Algebra